# Дата первого запуска программы

Tags: c#, winforms, properties

В чём ошибка? Всегда показывает текущую дату, а не первого запуска.

```
if (Properties.Settings.Default.fopdatebool == false)
{                
    Properties.Settings.Default.fopdate = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
    Properties.Settings.Default.fopdatebool = true;
}
```

Сейв стоит на `FormClosing`  и для других параметров все работает

```
 Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

**UPD**

---

Какая-то странность вообще происходит. Я выводил дату из сеттингов в текстбокс. Я убрал эту строку, но дата все равно продолжает отображаться и меняться там, если меняю дату на компе.

```
textBox1.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.fopdate.ToString();
```

Поиском проверил, нигде больше textBox1 и fopdate не встречаются. Что за мистика? Перезагрузил визуал студио, все так же... что делать?

**UPD 2**

---

Добавил новый текстбокс, так он вообще не отображается... В конструкторе есть, а в программе нету.

**UPD 3**

---

При запуске в Release все обновилось и работает, в Debug программа запускается в старой конфигурации, будто бы проект не собирается заново, а запускает старую версию, когда, кстати, и была эта ошибка. Я удалил полностью папку Debug, но программа все равно запускается в той версии (откуда, интересно, она берет её)

**Вот, в чём проблема**

---

Я новичёк, поэтому может что-то не понимаю... 
Всё обновилось когда я тыкнул **пересобрать решение**.  Программа заработала нормально. Но при следующих внесений правок, она опять не обновляется.

**РЕШЕНИЕ**

---

Причина была в том, что я менял дату на компьютере. Из-за этого сбой. После каждого изменения даты нужно пересобирать решение.

Comment: А разве у сеттингов автосейв? Разве не надо ещё вызвать что то типа `Properties.Settings.Default.Save()` ?

Comment: @Чад Сейв стоит на формклозинг и для других параметров все работает

Comment: Тогда перед сейвом выведите чему равны сеттинги, скорее всего fopdatebool == false в этот момент. Либо добавте сейв в условие if (хотя проверить что никто другой не меняет во время жизни программы тоже не мешает)